# A word or phrase meaning the opposite action of embedding

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When I want my document to be displayed the same on different devices, I can embed used fonts in the document.

But sometimes I want my documents to take less space so I want to remove previously embedded fonts.

How should I call the action in the second case?

Comment: Hmmm...for fonts in a document, there may be a better word, but I generally consider _to extract_ to be the opposite of _to embed_.  _Remove_ would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "[disembedding](http://www.whatdoesthatmean.com/dictionary/D/disembed.html)?"

> [In the font section, there's an option to disembed selected fonts.](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/442685)

Comment: There is also [unembed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unembed) but "disembed" seems like more common when you check Google Books (even there is no proper dictionary entry). Though there is also a sociological sense of [disembedding](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095721556) and it seems like it is the primary usage.

Answer (score 1):

Subsetting:

[Subsetting is the process of removing unnecessary glyphs from a font file, usually with the goal of reducing file size. This is particularly important for web fonts, since reducing file size often means reducing page load time.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Subsetting)